# What permissions needed for workflow to create subsite in sharepoint 2013 online?

Tags: workflow, permissions, sharepoint-online

I'm working in a sub-site of a sharepoint 2013 online site called "projects".

Following the blog post at http://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/8661/create-site-from-template-using-sharepoint-2013-workflow

In one section, it has the app permissions listed as

```
<AppPermissionRequests>
   <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Does the permissions need to be set to FullControl for the *sitecollection*?

Or will the call to **SP.WebInfoCreation** at **https://.sharepoint.com/projects/_api/web/webinfos/add** work at the, for example,  *sitecollection/web* scope?

I've tried the web scope and the call returned unauthorized, but I don't know if the authorization is due to the wrong scope level, or if it is due to other issues.

The powers-to-be are hesitating in giving full control at the site collection level.

I've done quite a bit of searching on msdn.  Is there a page that explains the required permission scopes required for the various rest api's?

Comment: Does the user have the ability to create a site?  Unless you're using app-only permissions, the user still needs permission to create a site.

Comment: Just finished reading the blog you posted.  Not sure how workflows work with app permissions, so my previous comment may not be helpful.

Comment: as mentioned in the post, the "Workflows can use app permissions" is active (step 6)

Comment: Yes, but with apps, the app requires permissions from the site, but the user still requires permissions as well (unless app-only permissions is enabled).  Not sure if this is the same with workflows using app permissions or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon experimentation,

```
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />
```

is required for a subsite to be created within a specific site collection.

I was not able to find any link that describes the permission scopes required for various REST api's